# Rollup build a React project import the modules in Node.js environment and get "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Headers')"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, rollup

I have a Github package built with React by Rollup.

In a project where it imports the modules from the Github package, I'm trying to run tests by Jest.

In every line of module import in the test files, I get the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Headers')

I'm assuming the rollup build config is the problem.

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import packageJson from './package.json';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.tsx',
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      exports: 'named',
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      exports: 'named',
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
    }),
    typescript({
      exclude: ['**/**.stories.tsx', '**/*.test.ts'],
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: ['node_modules/**'],
    }),
    json(),
  ],
};
```

The above is my rollup build settings.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: The problem most likely is that somewhere Jest is executing code that has network calls. Does the code being tested use Fetch, Axios, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I use network calls with axios. But I use msw and capture the request and returns a mock response.